# uploading multiple photos to specific location

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

I've been trying to create something that will upload multiple photos to a specific location and change it's name, tried to loop through files but something is not working and I quite can't figure out what that is! So please take a look and tell me what is wrong so I can learn and not make the same mistake again ! Thanks

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    if(isset($_POST['product_submit']))
    {
        if(!empty($_POST['product_name']) && !empty($_POST['product_author']) && !empty($_POST['product_price']) && empty($_POST['product_search']))
        {
            if(is_numeric($_POST['product_price']))
            {

                $auth_key = round(microtime(true));

                if(isset($_FILES['photos']) && !empty($_FILES['photos']))
                {
                    $image_path = "product_images";

                    foreach ($_FILES['photos']['name'] as $name => $value)
                    {

                        $filename = stripslashes($_FILES['photos']['name'][$name]);
                        $extension = getExtension($filename);
                        $extension = strtolower($extension);

                        if (($extension != "jpg") && ($extension != "jpeg") && ($extension != "png") && ($extension != "gif"))
                        {
                            $_SESSION['sucess'] = "Invalid extension.";

                            header("location: index.php");
                            exit();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $size = filesize($_FILES['photos']['tmp_name'][$name]);

                            if($size > 5120000)
                            {
                                $_SESSION['sucess'] = "You have exceeded the size limit.";

                                header("location: index.php");
                                exit();
                            }

                            $temp = explode('.', $filename);
                            $newfilename = mt_rand() . '_product.' . end($temp);
                            $name_path = "product_images/".$newfilename;

                            $suc = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photos']['tmp_name'][$name], $name_path);        


                            if($suc)
                            {
                                $stmt = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO images (auth_id, photo_location) VALUES (:code, :location)");
                                $stmt->bindParam(':code', $auth_key, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                                $stmt->bindParam(':location', $name_path, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                                $stmt->execute();       
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                $_SESSION['sucess'] = "Something went wrong!";

                                header("location: index.php");
                                exit();                                         
                            }
                        }   
                    }   
                }

                $query = "INSERT INTO products (name, author, price, date, code) VALUES (:name, :author, :price, NOW(), :code)";
                $stmt = $connection->prepare($query);

                $stmt->bindParam(':name', $_POST['product_name'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->bindParam(':author', $_POST['product_author'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->bindParam(':price', $_POST['product_price'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->bindParam(':code', $auth_key, PDO::PARAM_STR);

                $stmt->execute();

                if($stmt)
                {
                    $_SESSION['sucess'] = "Data inserted to database.";

                    header("location: index.php");
                    exit();
                }
                else
                {
                    $_SESSION['error'] = "Error while submiting data to database.";

                    header("location: index.php");
                    exit();
                }
            }
        }
        elseif (empty($_POST['product_name']) && empty($_POST['product_author']) && empty($_POST['product_price']) && !empty($_POST['product_search']))
        {
            $_SESSION['error'] = "You can't leave anything empty!";

            header("location: index.php");
            exit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First basic debugging step is to enable error reporting, then check your server error log

Comment: I am curious what will happen if I fake a post request saying the filename is `myfile/../../script.php`

Comment: I already did and there are no errors it goes straight to Data inserted to database.

Comment: @Xorifelse I'll edit

Comment: `$_FILES["photo"]["type"]` is user submitted data. I can fake that too. File can be something completely else.

Comment: $_FILES["photo"]["type"] does not exists on multiple file uploads.
It's $_FILES["photo"][0]["type"] , $_FILES["photo"][1]["type"]

Comment: Anyways... if you want to loop through all uploads, just use `foreach($_FILES['htmlattr'] as $file){ echo $file['tmp_name']; }` easier than a for loop.

Comment: I'll try to do it with a foreach now I'll get back with update once im finished

Comment: Updated, now it uploads 2 out of 4 files, and when i put isset check to see if photos have been selected it doesn't work, only when i remove it

Comment: @Xorifelse Now it works! But still the problem remains. How can i make it that uploading photos is not required ? For example if I want to add article without uploading files it says Invalid extension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your input file's name is photo[] you should use:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['photo']); $i++)
```

and then:

```
$_FILES['photo'][$i]['tmp_name']
```

and so on